# Pie Charts using StageXL?

Tags: dart, stagexl

Is there an easy way to draw a pie chart using StageXL?

I imagine the only other option (if I want the empty slice to be transparent) is to draw a vector pie chart and fill it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is an easier way, but you could implement one using ArcTo() as follows:

```dart
import 'dart:math' as Math;
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart';

void main() {
    // setup the Stage and RenderLoop
    var canvas = html.querySelector('#stage');
    var stage = new Stage(canvas);
    var renderLoop = new RenderLoop();
    renderLoop.addStage(stage);

    List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        entries.add(new Entry(i, "fgfgfgfgf ${i}"));
    }
    PieChart c = new PieChart(200, 200, 100, entries);
    stage.addChild(c);
}

class Entry {
    num val;
    String name;
    Entry(this.val, this.name);
}

class PieChart extends DisplayObjectContainer{
    num centerX;
    num centerY;
    num radius;
    List<int> _colors = [Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Yellow, Color.Cyan];
    int _c_index = 0;
    int get nextColor => _colors[_c_index=(++_c_index%_colors.length)]; 
    List<Entry> entries;
    PieChart(this.centerX, this.centerY, this.radius, this.entries){
        num sum = 0;
        for(Entry e in entries){
            sum+=e.val;
        }
        num angle = 0;
        for(Entry e in entries){
            addChild(new LabledPiePiece(this, angle, angle+=(e.val/sum)*360, nextColor, e));
        }
    }


}

class LabledPiePiece extends DisplayObjectContainer{
    LabledPiePiece(PieChart pie, num startAngleDeg, num endAngleDeg, int color, Entry e){
        num hDeg = (startAngleDeg+endAngleDeg)/2;
        addChild(new PiePieceHalf(pie, startAngleDeg, hDeg, color));
        addChild(new PiePieceHalf(pie, hDeg, endAngleDeg, color));
        TextField t = new TextField(e.name);
        t.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Arial', 16, Color.Black, align:TextFormatAlign.CENTER);
        t.y = pie.centerY+(pie.radius+t.textHeight)*Math.sin(hDeg/180*Math.PI);
        t.x = pie.centerX+(pie.radius+t.textHeight)*Math.cos(hDeg/180*Math.PI);
        t.rotation = hDeg/180*Math.PI+Math.PI/2;
        t.y = t.y - t.width*Math.sin(t.rotation)/2;
        t.x = t.x - t.width*Math.cos(t.rotation)/2;
        addChild(t);
    }
}

/**
 * draws a pie piece with max 180deg;
 */
class PiePieceHalf extends Shape{
    PieChart pie;
    num get centerX => pie.centerX;
    num get centerY => pie.centerY;
    num get radius => pie.radius;
    num startAngleRad;
    num endAngleRad;
    int color;

    PiePieceHalf(this.pie, num startAngleDeg, num endAngleDeg, this.color){
        this.startAngleRad = startAngleDeg/180*Math.PI;
        this.endAngleRad = endAngleDeg/180*Math.PI;
        draw();
    }

    void draw() {
        num controlAngle = (startAngleRad+endAngleRad)/2;
        num controlDist = radius/(Math.cos(startAngleRad-controlAngle));
        num controlX = centerX+Math.cos(controlAngle)*controlDist;
        num controlY = centerY+Math.sin(controlAngle)*controlDist;
        graphics.beginPath();
        graphics.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
        graphics.lineTo(centerX+Math.cos(startAngleRad)*radius, centerY+Math.sin(startAngleRad)*radius);
        graphics.arcTo(controlX, controlY, centerX+Math.cos(endAngleRad)*radius, centerY+Math.sin(endAngleRad)*radius, radius);
        graphics.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
        graphics.closePath();
        graphics.strokeColor(color);
        graphics.fillColor(color);
    }

}
```

This code is not perfect, it works though... except if you only add one pie piece... but it should not be to to difficult to handle this case...
Also it should not be to hard to add EmptyPiePieces... You would only have to extend the entry... maybe it wouldn't be too bad to make the color configurable via the entry as well...